# When creating the Laravel database tables, which of the terminal should I run first - Laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I want to create the database from the terminal. And in this section, when I say `php artisan migrate` and then `php artisan db: seed`, my tables are created. When I do the opposite, that is, when I first say `php artisan db: seed`, I get the table not found error.

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
>   Table 'fibonacci.roles' doesn't exist")
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\Fibonacci\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:463
>
> 2   PDOStatement::execute()
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\Fibonacci\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:463
>
> Please use the argument -v to see more details.

So is this the order for this error normal? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can't seed a table if the table doesn't exists. So run migrations and then seed.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what is `php artisan migrate` do is generate tables based on your migrations files and `php artisan db: seed` is to populate data inside specific table. Therefore, you need to have a table first then only data can be insert inside your table.

So to answer your question, yes the order for this error is normal.